# How to add a cookie to existing cookies in MechanicalSoup

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, mechanicalsoup, cookielib

I know MechanicalSoup has a function called set_cookiejar() but it replaces the current cookiejar completely. I want to know how to add new cookies to existing cookies.

Comment: It would be helpful to have some sample code

Comment: I figured it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("your website")

cookie_obj = requests.cookies.create_cookie(name='cookie name', value='cookie value', domain='domain name')
browser.session.cookies.set_cookie(cookie_obj)  # This will add your new cookie to existing cookies
```

Another way to do it is

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("your website")

new_cookie = {
    "name":'COOKIE_NAME',
    "value":'true',
    "version":0,
    "port":None,
    # "port_specified":False,
    "domain":'www.mydomain.com',
    # "domain_specified":False,
    # "domain_initial_dot":False,
    "path":'/',
    # "path_specified":True,
    "secure":False,
    "expires":None,
    "discard":True,
    "comment":None,
    "comment_url":None,
    "rest":{},
    "rfc2109":False
}

browser.session.cookies.set(**new_cookie)   # This will add your new cookie to existing cookies
```

Source: [How to add a cookie to the cookiejar in python requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224054/how-to-add-a-cookie-to-the-cookiejar-in-python-requests-library)