# Importing Firefox cookies into python from text file

Tags: python, firefox, cookies

I'm trying to load cookies into the python requests module . Using the FF extension 'advanced cookie manager' (https://www.facebook.com/cookiemanager ), I've exported cookies from firefox into a textfile that looks like:

```
.xxx.net    TRUE    /   FALSE   1435176898  _gat    1
.xxx.net    TRUE    /   FALSE   1498248358  _ga GA1.2.749243760.1435176299
.YYY.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1488730321  _ga GA1.2.630339061.1425658321
.YYY.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1472993710  __qca   P0-913150413-1425658321107
.YYY.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1488730321  __gads  ID=8edab7af1673d945:T=1425658321:S=ALNI_Ma6b9RCM4Cm7IGSojNoWU5DohhJ0w
www.YYY.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1457194477  htg_subform_hide    1
```

I've come across [How to send cookies in a post request with the Python Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library), but the accepted example:

```
cookie = {'enwiki_session': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}
```

refers to only one field. Each record exported in my file has 7 fields which I assume some of which are

```
domain , path , expires, Name
```

What is the best way to import these cookies into python so I can use them with requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advance Cookie Manager exports the cookies in to text file in the below format:

`HOST   isDomainCookie   PATH   IsSecure   EXPIRY   NAME   VALUE`

NOTE: TAB is the delimiter between the fields

Comment: Could you please describe your answer more detailed and format your code correctly.