# How can I bypass a cookie agreement page while web scraping using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I hurt my nose to a cookie agreement page...

What I am doing:

```
import requests
url = "https://stockhouse.com/community/bullboards/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

which returns HTML from a cookie agreement page. What I am then looking for is to bypass this page and scrape the content of the actual page once we accept the cookies...

I tried the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248266/bypassing-intrusive-cookie-statement-with-requests-library):

```
cookies = dict(BCPermissionLevel='PERSONAL')
html = requests.get(website, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, cookies=cookies)
```

but I still get the html from the cookie page.

Note: I succeeded using Selenium, but selenium is a is very inefficient last recourse...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this site it's enough to specify "dummy" cookie `privacy-policy`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stockhouse.com/community/bullboards/"

cookies = {
    'privacy-policy': '1,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for h3 in soup.select('h3'):
    print(h3.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints the titles:

```
Perfect timing: Mach offer no good as per AMF
'Explosive' Move Up Next Week"
Repsol/ Tullow
Assessment
$5.96
Possible Deal?
Massive Investor(s) Buys Over 1 Million JE Shares Last Close
This CEO is really on the ball , right flubber
slow bb
Situation
Loadddddd
Numerology of the number 36
TIMBERRRR!!.. it will go down fast to $1.50
Employees in the know do the right thing Whistelblow
News finally
Will be bought out...halt coming
Green today
Somebody is buying
re re :350 mil is not enough
And Trump fk up another day
```