# Bypass cookie agreement page while web scraping using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies

I am facing an issue with google agreement page cookies after scraping on a redirect google url.

I am trying to scrape from different pages on Google News uri, but when i run this code:

```
req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

with "headers" = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.422.0 Safari/534.1', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'DNT': '1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language': 'it-IT'}
and for example URL = https://news.google.com/./articles/CAIiEMb3PYSjFFVbudiidQPL79QqGQgEKhAIACoHCAow-ImTCzDRqagDMKiIvgY?hl=it&gl=IT&ceid=IT%3Ait 

the "request.content" is the HTMLs code of agreement cookies page by Google.
```

I have tried also to convert the redirect link into a normal link but the response gives me the redirect link to [this](https://consent.google.com/m?continue=https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEMLGtBKUToKl3z9uwErTOuAqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowo7uICzD8lIcDMKuBnAY?hl%3Dit%26amp;gl%3DIT%26amp;ceid%3DIT:it&gl=FR&m=0&pc=n&hl=it&src=1)

I have the same problem related to this question ([How can I bypass a cookie agreement page while web scraping using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462036/how-can-i-bypass-a-cookie-agreement-page-while-web-scraping-using-python)).

Anyway, the solution proposed in that works only for the specific site.

**Note:** the entire code worked until  few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding the line

> `'Cookie':'CONSENT=YES+cb.20210418-17-p0.it+FX+917; '`

to the request header.

Although the page returned by the request is still a Google page, but that page contains the link to the site from which the request originated.

So, once I got the page I did some more scraping so that I could get the link and start the request I wanted.

Comment: For those who ended up here, here's a similar discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560247/bypassing-eu-consent-request