# Bypassing EU consent request

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I've been trying to extract data from google searches but I'm not able to bypass the "Before you continue to Google Search" consent form.

I tried to find a workoround and [saw](https://github.com/benbusby/whoogle-search/issues/243) that others have suggested using the argument `CONSENT=PENDING+999` , or something along the lines of `CONSENT = YES+HU.hu+V10+B+256` in the get request. Unfortunately, I couldn't make the former work and in the latter case, I'm not entirely sure what the last three elements should be replaced with.

I attach a sample code below from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-google-search-results-using-python-beautifulsoup/).

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {'User-Agent':'Chrome 83 (Toshiba; Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2367M CPU @ 1.40 GHz)'\
           'Windows 7 Home Premium',
           'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;'\
           'q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
           #'cookie': 'CONSENT = YES+HU.hu+V10+B+256' # what are the last three elements?  
           'cookie':'CONSENT=PENDING+999'
           }

text= "geeksforgeeks"
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text
  
request_result=requests.get( url , headers = headers) # here's where the trouble happens 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "html.parser")

print(soup) # not what one would expect

heading_object=soup.find_all( 'h3' ) 
  
for info in heading_object:
    print(info.getText())
    print("------")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, indeed Google uses the `CONSENT` cookie to determine whether the consent popup will show or not. I have played around with the cookie by adjusting the value and I can conclude as of writing, setting `CONSENT` cookie value to `YES+` is enough to stop the consent window from showing.

In your code, you attempted to pass the cookie via the `headers` parameter. I recommend using the `cookies` parameter.

Adjust your code with this (and remove cookies from the headers):

```
request_result = requests.get( url, headers = headers, cookies = {'CONSENT' : 'YES+'} )
```

---

My output after running your code with my solution:

```
GeeksforGeeks
------
GeeksforGeeks - YouTube
------
GeeksforGeeks | LinkedIn
------
GeeksforGeeks (@geeks_for_geeks) • Instagram photos and videos
------
GeeksforGeeks - Twitter
------
GeeksforGeeks - Home | Facebook
------
Geeks for Geeks - Crunchbase Company Profile & Funding
------
```

Comment: This no longer works, you still get to the consent.google.com site, even with the cookie

Answer (score 0):

An update 2 years later. I had the same problem and found the solution in the [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/benbusby/whoogle-search/issues/1053) of Whoole Search project adding 2 cookies, CONSENT and SOCS

Below a working example based on the original post:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"}

cookies = {
    "CONSENT": "PENDING+987",
    "SOCS": "CAESHAgBEhJnd3NfMjAyMzA4MTAtMF9SQzIaAmRlIAEaBgiAo_CmBg"
}

text = "geeksforgeeks"
url = f"https://google.com/search?q={text}"

request_result = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "html.parser")

heading_object = soup.find_all("h3")

for info in heading_object:
    print(info.getText())
    print("------")
```