# Consent to cookies on google domain REST request?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, request, get

Need to pull a string/array from google maps (e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/@/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!11m1!2sVL_AlqDaR1ymbWlQfsT7Jw) preferably using a simple GET as anything more seems unnecessarily excessive.  But previously apparently working methods ([Bypassing EU consent request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560247/bypassing-eu-consent-request)) no longer work.

Any way to manage(consent or reject... just bypass one way or another) the google cookie consent redirect?

Ideally with simple requests in javascript but I've also toyed with Puppeteer.  No issues with the cookie there, but the resulting page.content seems like a generator with the underlying data that i'm looking for not being processed.

Specifically looking for a section that reads `(function(){window.APP_OPTIONS=...`