# Import cookie - Robobrowser - Python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, robobrowser

I'm looking to import a cookie using `robobrowser`. So I define:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

cookie={'name':'sc_device_auth',
    'value':'abcdef',
    'domain':'www.url.com/'}

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True,\
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'\
        ,parser='lxml')

browser.session.cookies.update(cookie)
```

but, `browser` doesn't import `cookie` properly:

```
In [0]: browser.session.cookies
Out [0]: <RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='domain',value='www.url.com/', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False),
    Cookie(version=0, name='name', value='sc_device_auth', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False),
    Cookie(version=0, name='value', value='abcdef', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)
                           ]>
```

`browser` doesn't import my cookie as one cookie, but as 3 differents cookies...
As `Robobrowser` is `Requests` based, I used: [How to send cookies in a post request with the Python Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a partial awnser to my question.
I define:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

cookie={'sc_device_auth':'abcdef'}

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True,\
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/40.1'\
    ,parser='lxml')

browser.session.cookies.update(cookie)
```

With cookie defined with this new dict, seem to work. But the cookie is not domain reserved.

Not of perfect solution. But works.