# How can I figure it out what is wrong in my Amazon Price Tracker project?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to create a program which send an e-mail when the product price below then 200$ but it doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
line 22, in <module>
    title = soup.find(id="Electric Pressure Cookers").get_text().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

ı don't understand why it's not working. so if someone help me ı would very happy

```
import requests
import lxml
import smtplib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075CYMYK6?ref_=cm_sw_r_cp_ud_ct_FM9M699VKHTT47YD50Q6&th=1"
header = {
    "User-Agent": "my_user_agent",
    "Accept-Language": "my_accept_language",
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())

price = soup.find(class_="a-offscreen").get_text()
price_without_currency = price.split("$")[1]
price_as_float = float(price_without_currency)
print(price_as_float)

title = soup.find(id='electrical cooker').get_text().strip()
print(title)

BUY_PRICE = 200

if price_as_float < BUY_PRICE:
    message = f"{title} is now {price}"

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        result = connection.login("my_gmail@gmail.com", "my_password")
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr= "my_gmail@gmail.com",
            to_addrs= "my_gmail@gmail.com",
            msg =f"Subject:Amazon Price Alert!\n\n{message}\n{url}".encode("utf-8",))
```

ı were expecting it send me an e-mail which says: ptoduct price is {product_price} now, so what do you think about what ı must to do for work the program

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup/response to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* Do you find the element with `id="Electric Pressure Cookers"` in there? Based on the error it seems not the case - check if you find a hint that amazon blocks you from scraping, because they do not like it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you hit the URL, the Amazon popup says to accept cookies, so I just added it.

references: [Scraping a webpage using Python (beautiful soup) that requires "I agree to cookies" button being clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171353/scraping-a-webpage-using-python-beautiful-soup-that-requires-i-agree-to-cooki)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075CYMYK6?ref_=cm_sw_r_cp_ud_ct_FM9M699VKHTT47YD50Q6&th=1"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies={'__hs_opt_out': 'no'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
price = soup.find('span', class_='a-price-whole').get_text()
title = soup.find('span', id='productTitle').get_text()
print(price)
print(title)
```

[image]