# Allow Third Party Cookies on newer versions of chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, puppeteer, webdriver-io, third-party-cookies

I encountered the problem with chromedriver 121 and above - it looks like Google Chrome 121 introduced changes to its handling of third-party cookies, which could potentially affect how automated tests interact with websites that rely on third-party cookies for various functionalities.

Is there any way to **forcefully allow** third-party-cookies on the chrome under automated tests ?

approaches in **chromeoptions** such as **args** :

*--allow-third-party-cookies,
--disable-web-security,
--disable-site-isolation-trials,
--disable-incognito,
--no-sandbox,*

or **prefs**:

- 'profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies': 1,
  'profile.block_third_party_cookies': false,
  'profile.content_settings.exceptions.cookies.*.setting': 1*

**are not working** - it seems that chrome under test just overrides such security work-arounds

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78033218/how-can-i-figure-it-out-what-is-wrong-in-my-amazon-price-tracker-project/78035233?noredirect=1#comment137650057_78035233)

Comment: Find information about third-party cookie blocking in Chromium-based browsers at https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd.