# Unable to download a specific webpage in Python3x with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

The following code works on several other URLs but does not work for a specific URL. Not sure why and how to workaround it?
**For money.usunew.com it hangs.** But for all other URLs that I tried such as usatoday.com it works.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://money.usnews.com' # does NOT work for this URL but works for 'https://www.usatoday.com' 

result = requests.get(url)

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the website is blocking the spider.
You can add `timeout` to check it out.

```
result = s.post('https://money.usnews.com', timeout=15)
```

You got:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='money.usnews.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)
```

Similar question:

[How to send cookies in a post request with the Python Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library)