# Get source code of website with Python without being redirected?

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, python-requests

I'm trying to get the source-code of a website: "https://004.lmvz.ch/disdonc/block/5d3f06e7f323590019034257/test?identifier=004lmvzch-disdonc-5d3f06e7f323590019034257&identifier=004lmvzch-disdonc-5d3f06e7f323590019034257". But if I'm trying it with requests:

```
import requests
url = "https://004.lmvz.ch/disdonc/block/5d3f06e7f323590019034257/test?identifier=004lmvzch-disdonc-5d3f06e7f323590019034257&identifier=004lmvzch-disdonc-5d3f06e7f323590019034257"
print(requests.get(url).text)
```

But it returns the sourcecode of the login page: "https://login.lmvz.ch", so I think I get redirected. How can I bypass this? I tried it with: allow_redirects=False, but it does still not work.

Greetings,
Dave

Comment: You may need to use post instead of get, and add additional data like cookies,

Comment: @FilipMłynarski I've tried it, but it loads a webpage that says "MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

Comment: @Carcigenicate It gives me the source code of the webpage in the response tab

Answer (score 0):

It's because it requires authentication info, the website automatically redirects to login page if you don't provide it.

Solution:

1. Login with valid credentials
2. Get the authen session info
3. Add authen info to header (in cookie) to request.

Check it out: [How to send cookies in a post request with the Python Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library)

Comment: This led me to a page that says: MethodNotAllowedHttpException as title

Comment: Did you try to change GET to POST? Please read my anwser, I didn't suggest you to do that. Just login (manualy), copy the right cookie to GET request in python.