# Convert C# post request to Python

Tags: python, c#

```
var client = new RestClient(Url.Combine(sharepointSiteUrl, "_api"));
client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
client.CookieContainer.SetCookies(siteUri, cred.GetAuthenticationCookie(siteUri));

var digestReq = new RestRequest("contextinfo", Method.POST);
digestReq.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var digest = client.Execute<dynamic>(digestReq).Data;
```

I am not familiar with **C#** `POST` calls. I am trying to convert this code to **Python** and wanted to understand how to do it.

I tried looking up requests in **Python** but i do not understand how cookies work there and how to execute these calls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library

Comment: @Jisson
I understand this line
var digestReq = new RestRequest("contextinfo", Method.POST);
can be converted to digestReq = requests.post("contextinfo") but dont understand the two lines later.         

digestReq.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var digest = client.Execute<dynamic>(digestReq).Data;

Comment: I believe its the request object( method is POST), Instead of converting C#  code into line by line. just do the following,
import requests, cookies = {'some_key': '12345678'}  resp =requests.post('the url', cookies=cookies)

Comment: how about the header and what does contextinfo mean?

Comment: I don't have C# knowledge, you can't find line by line replacement of a c# code to python.

Comment: The `accept` header is a common one - you can look up what it's used for. If you don't know about headers, then perhaps a bit of reading on how HTTP works would help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP

Comment: In any case, you do need to understand how both libraries work to make HTTP requests with them. In your example code in comments, you were using "contextinfo" as the URL in the call to `requests.post` - I doubt that's what you wanted.

Comment: contextinfo: If `sharepointSiteUrl` is `https://www.example.com/` then I would expect the client initialization line combined with "contextinfo" to result in a POST request to `https://www.example.com/_api/contextinfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following lines of code to send a post request to a server resource

```
import requests  # you need to install requests library  (pip install requests)
my_cookie = {'some_key': 'value}
resp = requests.post('the url', cookies=cookies)  # request.get
print(resp.status_code) # print the http response code (200, 400, 500 etc)
print(resp.text)        # shows the text format of the response
print(resp.json())      # if the data returned by the server is json
```

Variable resp will have the response from the server. use it to read the data returned by the server.

Comment: The original sets the accept header to 'application/json'.